# how to get value in a table from another table on Parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform, cloud

I have 2 tables on parse.com backend

1. Ratings
2. Places

I want to retrieve the data from the "Ratings" table and save it to the "Places" table.
I.e.: The Ratings table will have different ratings marked by different users
under the "UserRating" column.
I want to get the Average of this column and then save it to the Places class under rating columns.
So, I can display the average rating.

Comment: Have you used relations in parse.com? If not you can try using relations

Comment: @HarshaVardhan, I don't think the OP is aiming to relate the two classes, but to summarize data from one in the other.  Please post the column names/types for both classes.  I think the solution is probably a beforeSave on Ratings that computes the average incrementally.

Comment: use cloud code and use the promise feature of parse